# Hiding and Showing HTML Elements with Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, hide

I'm trying to hide and show HTML Elements by using javascript. It all works well, but the result isn't longer available then 1 Second. After one second, the element, that is displayed by default appears and the element that should be shown is hidden.

Here below I posted my sample code. I created an element called selected, that keeps a value, that tells which paragraph is actually shown. If I click on next, I want the next Paragraph to be shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<selected id="displayedResults" value="0">


</selected>
<div>
<p id="results_0" style=""> Result 0 </p>
<p id="results_1" style="display: none;"> Result 1 </p>
<p id="results_2" style="display: none;"> Result 2 </p>
<p id="results_3" style="display: none;"> Result 3 </p>
<p id="results_4" style="display: none;"> Result 4 </p>
<p id="results_5" style="display: none;"> Result 5 </p>

<a onclick="previousResults()" href="">Previous</a>
<a onclick="nextResults()" href="">Next</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function previousResults()
{
    var index = document.getElementById("displayedResults").getAttribute("value");
    var rslString = "results_";
    if(index>0)
    {
        document.getElementById(rslString.concat(index)).style.display='none';
        index=index-1;
        document.getElementById(rslString.concat(index)).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("displayedResults").setAttribute("value",index);                    
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function nextResults()
{
    var index = document.getElementById("displayedResults").getAttribute("value");
    var rslString = "results_";
    if(index<5)
    {
        document.getElementById(rslString.concat(index)).style.display='none';
        index++;
        document.getElementById(rslString.concat(index)).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("displayedResults").setAttribute("value",index);                    
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your links are reloading the page when you click on them, so you're seeing the results of your JavaScript, then the page reloads and it resets back to the starting state. The simplest solution would be to modify your HTML for the `<a>` elements to this:

```
<a onclick="previousResults(); return false;" href="">Previous</a>
<a onclick="nextResults(); return false;" href="">Next</a>
```

The `return false` will prevent the default behaviour of that action - in this case following the link - thereby preventing the page reload.

In addition to that, there's no `<selected>` element in HTML. You'd be better served by using a hidden input, so replace this:

```
<selected id="displayedResults" value="0">


</selected>
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" id="displayedResults" value="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<selected id="displayedResults" value="0"></selected>`

That ain't gonna work ;-)
- Edit: Oke, yes it can work but it's not valid HTML...

`<select id="displayedResults">
<option value="0">zero</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 0):

It is because your page is reloading in each click. Change that anchor tag to another tag like span or something..

```
<span onclick="previousResults()">Previous</span>
<span onclick="nextResults()">Next</span>
```

Comment: While that works - using meaningless markup shouldn't be encouraged. It only works because span's don't have a default click handler. -1.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
return false;
```

on each function

use jquery than traditional javascript
to hide result 1
`$('#results_1').hide();`
to unhide just use
`$('#results_1').show();`

please tell what you are trying to achieve. I think you are doing it in a complex way.

Answer (score 0):

The page is reloaded once you click the previous and next link. So please do as follows :

```
<a onclick="previousResults()" href="javascript:">Previous</a>
<a onclick="nextResults()" href="javascript:">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `return false;` in the `onclick` attributes, in order to prevent the browser refreshing the page.

See http://jsfiddle.net/xZSyz/